# Constant time evaluation

Tags: c, microcontroller

I can't get this line to run in constant time on my micro-controller:

```
int zz,yy; //some binary variables  

zz = (yy) ? 0 : (1 & zz);
```

I tried to change it to

```
zz = (yy) ? (0 & zz) : (1 & zz);
```

because `&` should force an evaluation of the right side even though the left side defines the result as far as I know. But it did not help.

Can anyone suggest me a solution how to make this line constant time?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'constant time'? I would consider this O(1), so do you mean something else, or ...?

Comment: by constant time, I mean that it always should take `x` cycles running on my microcontroller,  `x` should be equal for both cases `0` and `1&zz`

Comment: It entirely depends on your compiler and its settings. Maybe `(!yy) * (1 & zz)` helps?

Comment: What system do you have that needs optimization on this level?

Comment: it is not about optimization, it is about being constant time (which often implies slower code)

Comment: Take a look at [Hacker's Delight](https://www.hackersdelight.org/) for more ideas. Or search for "bit twiddling".

Comment: The time difference is probably because you have a branch. Try `zz &= !yy` instead.

Comment: How does it run then?  What do you mean with constant time?  Have you considered instruction caching effects? what architecture are you running that on?  Have you had a look at the assembler code?

Comment: what i mean by const time is already discussed in above comments. and yes i did, no caches, branch prediction. quentins suggestion worked fine

Answer (score -1):

> It entirely depends on your compiler and its settings. Maybe (!yy) *
>   (1 & zz) helps?

@Quentin